# Why does interactive rebase open VS Code and why can't I run WebStorm from terminal?

Tags: bash, git, command-line-interface, editor, webstorm

I just installed WebStorm on my laptop. However, there are two issues. Interactive rebase (`git rebase -i HEAD~<insert_number>`) opens me a VS Code window for some reason instead of doing it in the WebStorm terminal window and I can't run WebStorm from my terminal like I do with VS Code and a window pops up like one below.

[image: Error launching WebStorm]

Answer (score 2):

Check the value of your git config core.editor. I have mine set to notepad++ and I'd suspect that you have yours set to VS Code.

```
[core]
editor = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe' -nosession -notabbar
```